How to publicly share a layer that is automatically overwritten in ArcGIS Online
I have a layer in ArcGIS Online that is overwritten every morning and I want to update it on a map. I do the overwrite using the features.manage_data.overlay_layers in a Jupyter notebook that is scheduled to run every morning. This layer is then publicly shared as a map in a dashboard. The suggestion is to create a view from this editable layer and use that instead. In that case, the code cannot be run and gives the following error:
Cannot perform overwrite: the specified portal item is referenced by other portal items
It suggests deleting the view layer to rewrite it. However, when I want to make the layer itself public, it gives the warning suggesting not to share an editable layer publicly. Is there any solution for this situation?

I don't know if this would work for AGOL layers, but I used to use arcpy.management.TruncateTable and arcpy.management.Append to update Portal feature layers that needed to be be replacedwithout actually overwriting.

The easiest way to do this is from a local map sevice (vice an AGOL hosted service). Then you can play fun games with databases like using a "swap" between a table and a partition to atomically change the contents of a table in under a millisecond (no down time at all).
